# AWK menu shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I need a help regarding awk `print f` in shell script.

Please see the below my script

```
#!/bin/sh
date_time=`date '+%d-%b-%Y_%H:%M:%S'`
usr="test"

echo "Hai" | awk -V '{
printf("==========================================\n");
printf("|%10s|%10s|\n","Date" $date_time);
printf("|%10s|%10s|\n","user" $usr);
printf("==========================================\n");
}'
```

I want output as below

```
==============================
| date | 14-Jan-2016_16:49:40|
| user | Test                |
==============================
```

Comment: Are you trying to learn awk? You could get the needed output using printf alone

Answer (score 1):

You  might be looking for this :

```
#!/bin/sh
date_time=`date '+%d-%b-%Y_%H:%M:%S'`
usr="test"
printf "==================================\n"
printf "|%10s |%20s| \n" "Date" "$date_time"
printf "|%10s |%-20s| \n" "User" "$usr"  # here - before 20 is for left align
printf "==================================\n"
```

If for some reason `awk` is mandatory try the below stuff :

```
#!/bin/sh
date_time=`date '+%d-%b-%Y_%H:%M:%S'`
usr="test"
awk -v date_time="$date_time" -v usr="$usr" 'BEGIN{
printf "==================================\n"
printf "|%10s |%20s|\n","Date",date_time
printf "|%10s |%-20s|\n","User",usr
printf "==================================\n"
}' </dev/null
```

Comment: You should probably quote all the variables, otherwise `printf` will generate multiple lines of output, and/or the shell will do funny stuff with the value when interpolating it.  See further http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable